# Given 2 one dimensional arrays which are sorted in ascending order.Write a program to merge them into a single sorted array in ascending order

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I would like to know how i can make this code better. I cant get it to sort the joint array in ascending order without manipulating the other 2 arrays. Kindly assist

Solution:
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a() As Integer = {2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 3}
    Dim B() As Integer = {10, 8, 6, 9, 7}
    Dim value = A.Union(B)

    Console.WriteLine("Set A")
    Array.Sort(A)
    For Each srt As Integer In a
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", srt)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("set B")
    Array.Sort(B)
    For Each srt As Integer In B
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", srt)

    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Joining")
    For Each c As Integer In value
        Console.WriteLine(c)
    Next c
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: if i am to switch say 3 and 7 from their arrays, the joint array will not sort in ascending order or if i put random numbers in both arrays the result wont be sorted

Comment: Does `Union` perform some ordering? To my understanding, the output will not mecessarily be sorted.

Comment: I honestly don't know a whole lot about unions, but i do not think it performs any ordering but is a merge syntax if i am right. How can have my output sorted?

Comment: `Dim c = a.Concat(B).OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToArray`

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the task of merging two sorted arrays in linear time can be done by iteratively deciding from which array the value is to be taken. I have no experience wit Visual Basic, but can explain the idea as follows with some C#-ish pseudocode.

```
int[] A; // first sorted array
int[] B; // second sorted array
int[] C = new int[A.length + B.length]; // will contain the result;

int ia = 0; // index for A
int ib = 0; // index for B
int ic = 0; // index for C

while (ic < c.length) // iterate while C is not filled
{
    if (ia == A.length) // A is consumed, must take from B
    {
        C[ic] = B[ib];
        ib = ib + 1;
    }
    else if (ib == B.length) // B is consumed, must take from A
    {
        C[ic] = A[ia];
        ia = ia + 1;
    }
    else // neither A nor B is consumed, must make real comparison
    {
        if (A[ia] < B[ib]) // take from A
        {
            C[ic] = A[ia];
            ia = ia + 1;
        }
        else // take from B
        {
            C[ic] = B[ib];
            ib = ib + 1;
        }
    }
    ic = ic + 1; // step forward in C
}
```